# Hint on binomial sum involving roots of unity

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers

While preparing for an exam, I am currently working on the following task:

Let $n$ be a natural number, and $\zeta_n$ a primitive $n$th root of unity. Show that 
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j=1}^{n} \binom{\zeta_n^j}{n} = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} 
\end{equation*}

It can be assumed to be known that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \zeta_n^k = 1$ for $n=1$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \zeta_n^k = 0$ otherwise.

I would be grateful for some simple hints for proving this equation. The task was given in a couse on combinatorics, and its solution is obviously somehow related to the Stirling numbers of the first kind. Please do not post the full solution.

Comment: Hint: $\dbinom{x}{n} = \dfrac{1}{n!} x^n + \left(\text{a linear combination of } x^i \text{ with } 1 \leq i < n \right) + \left(-1\right)^n$.

Comment: Actually, this has little to do with any combinatorics. Just expand the polynomials in $\zeta_n$ and recall that the sum of $\zeta_n^{jk}$ for $j=1$ to $n$ is $0$ if $k$ is not divisible by $n$ and $n$ otherwise.

Comment: The equations that "can be assumed to be known" are slightly insufficient. I suggest instead using $\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\zeta_n^k\right)^m = 0$ when $n \nmid m$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\zeta_n^k\right)^m = n$ when $n \mid m$. (Of course, you *can* derive these two equations from yours, but they are less misleading.)

Comment: How is $\binom{\zeta_n^j}{n}$ defined?  I'm not familiar with this usage.

Comment: Thank you for all comments so far. The binomial term was not formally defined, but I assume that $\binom{\zeta^j_n}{n} = \frac{\zeta^j_n \times (\zeta^j_n -1) \times \dots \times (\zeta^j_n -n + 1)}{n!}$